# Bind dynamic loaded content to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to bind some dynamic content, loaded by jQuery, to Angular but i couldn't get it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var module = angular.module('ctrl', []);

        module.directive('helpMe', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div><button ng-click="clicker()">Click 1</button><button ng-click="create()">Create</button><div ng-hide="true">FooBar</div></div>',
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.clicker = function () {
                        console.log('Clicked...');
                    };

                    $scope.create = function () {
                        $('#foo').contents().clone().appendTo('#bar');
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrl">
    <div id="foo">
        <help-me></help-me>
    </div>
    <div id="bar">

    </div>
</body>
```

If i click the "Click 1" button, the console logs it. If i click the "create" button, a new set of buttons appears. But the new buttons don't work. I could not find out how to get this work. Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to use jQuery with angularjs for a small components, it better to include it in controller rather than directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `$compile` on the HTML string before inserting it into the DOM so that angular gets a chance to perform the binding.

```
$scope.create = function() {
    var clone = $('#foo').contents().clone();
    $compile(clone)($scope);
    $('#bar').append(clone);
}
```

check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L9JJxzMlStSBhsFcxzrs?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var module = angular.module('ctrl', []);

        module.directive('helpMe', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div><button ng-click="clicker()">Click 1</button><button ng-click="create()">Create</button><div ng-hide="true">FooBar</div></div>',
                controller: ['$scope','$compile' function($scope,$compile) {
                    $scope.clicker = function () {
                        console.log('Clicked...');
                    };

                    $scope.create = function () {
                        $('#foo').contents().clone().appendTo('#bar');
                        $compile($('#bar'))($scope);
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ctrl">
    <div id="foo">
        <help-me></help-me>
    </div>
    <div id="bar">

    </div>
</body>
```